# How do I stop stretching during window re-size in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, .net

In my windowed mode XNA game when the user resizes the window the game stops updating the window and the last frame drawn is stretched and distorted until the user releases the mouse and the resize completes.

Is there any way to have the game continue to run "normally", updating frames and redrawing the screen, during the resize event?

I realize that keeping the render loop going while resizing may not be possible or recommended due do hardware managed resources getting continually created and destroyed, but is there any way to stop the ugly stretching?  Ideally by leaving the existing frame unscaled in the top left, or with a black screen if that isn't possible.

Comment: Register an event for the window resize and update the GraphicsDevice resolution. This may update the aspect ratio and fix the stretching.

Comment: I don't know about C#/XNA, but in C++/D3D I just had the render loop running in a separate thread from the main thread with the message loop. The main thread performs the buffer resize when a resize event occurs, synchronized through a mutex.

Comment: Gustavo, I already handle that event for other purposes in the game.  Unfortunately it doesn't fire until after the user releases the mouse when the re-size is complete.

Comment: [This question/answer pair](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51376/288) might be helpful. It tells you how to continue rendering (although it doesn't fix stretching).

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 3 messages that you can track.

- `WM_SIZE` - window resizing, mini/maximization, fullscreen/windowed switching. You shall read into wParam to find out what exactly happened and to lParam for current size.
- `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` - begin window resizing in windowed mode
- `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` - end window resizing in windowed mode

Usually you will not want resize your app every frame between WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE because its too way slooow and ugly. But give it a try, its surely nicely than stretching, maybe you'll like it =)

```
case WM_SIZE:
    // Save the new client area dimensions.
    m_ptViewportSize.x  = LOWORD(lParam);
    m_ptViewportSize.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    if( wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED )
    {
        m_bAppSuspended = true;
        m_bMinimized = true;
        m_bMaximized = false;
    }
    else if( wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED )
    {
        m_bAppSuspended = false;
        m_bMinimized = false;
        m_bMaximized = true;
        OnResize();
    }
    else if( wParam == SIZE_RESTORED )
    {
        // Restoring from minimized state
        if( m_bMinimized )
        {
            m_bAppSuspended = false;
            m_bMinimized = false;
            OnResize();
        }
        // Restoring from maximized state
        else if( m_bMaximized )
        {
            m_bAppSuspended = false;
            m_bMaximized = false;
            OnResize();
        }
        else if( m_bResizing )
        {
            // Resizing in processs
            // You woldn't wanto to handle a massive stream of
            // WM_SIZE here because buffers resizing is very slow
        }
        else
        {
            // Resizing finished and you can handle it. For ex. with 
            // m_SwapChain->SetFullscreenState
            OnResize();
        }

    }
    return 0;

// WM_EXITSIZEMOVE is sent when the user grabs the resize bars.
case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
    m_bAppSuspended = true;
    m_bResizing  = true;
    g_pTimer->Stop();
    return 0;
// WM_EXITSIZEMOVE is sent when the user releases the resize bars.
// Here we reset everything based on the new window dimensions.
case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
    m_bAppSuspended = false;
    m_bResizing  = false;
    g_pTimer->Start();
    OnResize();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Handling windows messages in .NET involves overriding `System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc()`.  When working in XNA, you don't have direct access to a `Form` to override that method.  While it is possible to do, it's not a trivial amount of work and would have to circumvent XNA's design.

Comment: Should someone choose to take this path, this list of wm_* constants should prove to be useful: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html

Comment: Like others have said, I would still need a way to short circuit the XNA "engine" and cause it to draw again during the correct events.  From what I can tell XNA sort of "goes to sleep" during the resize procedure.